# Zend 2 does not work with netbeans

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to build a small php web application using Zend 2 framework.  I am totally new to this framework and I encounter some configuration problems.

I am using windows 7, netbeans 7.4 and WAMP server.
I have downloaded the zend skeleton application and link it with netbeans via Tools ->  Options -> Php -> Zend 2 tab.  I have also downloaded the msi for composer and install it.  I then link it the composer.phar file with netbeans via Tools -> Options -> Composer tab.  I have also configure the PHP interpreter found in Tools-> Options-> General to the php.exe file.

After doing all of these, I managed to create a new PHP project using Zend 2 framework.  I have also added the library folder of Zend 2 framework package in the include_path folder of this project in case it is needed.

If I browse to `http://localhost/MyProjectName` I can see the directory of my project.  But if I go to `http://localhost/MyProjectName/public/index.php` I get the following error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

The apache error log gives the following error:

> C:/wamp/www/MyProjectName/public/.htaccess: Invalid command
>   'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Isn’t public/index.php the main point of the application?  Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you enable mod_rewrite for apache.

Do this by left clicking the wamp icon -> apache -> apache modules -> rewrite_module.

Comment: This is at least a start. I can't determine if the way you installed zf2 is the proper ine. I use git to do this ( much like the zf2 documentation suggests )

Comment: Ok I have enabled mod_rewrite.  I then uncommented (remove ";") "extension=php_openssl.dll" and "extension=php_phar.dll" lines from c:\wampp\bin\php\php.x.y.z\php.ini.  
I then opened a cmd and located to my project directory and run "php composer.phar install".  Now I can see the welcome page.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad I could be of help. Don't forget that php extensions and apache modules can both be enabled via the wamp tray icon menu. ( although you are right to edit the ini, as there's a different ini for php commandline as there is for apache )

Comment: Actually I first tried to edit it from wampp but it did not work. When I located to the php.ini from disk I realized that the two lines were still commented.  So wampp so changing a different ini.

Comment: Exactly. It had me confused before as well. You can configure apache to use the same php.ini as the commandline php.exe. Or the other way around ( see: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php ). But it's not necessarily a bad thing to keep them separated, it's common practice too.